# What is the intersection between complete bipartite graphs and complements of bipartite graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

For context, I am in an intro Graph theory course. I know that the complement of a bipartite graph can be bipartite, but I don't know how to determine all of them and whether they can be complete. I assume the intersection is not empty but I am not sure. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complement of a complete bipartite graph $K_{m,n}$ is the union of the two complete graphs $K_m\cup K_n$.  That complement is bipartite if and only if $m<3$ and $n<3$.  If $m,n>0$ then the complement will never be complete since it is not even connected.

Comment: Thank you so much! Why m,n<3 though?

Comment: @Maria because anything larger than that would have an odd cycle, like a cycle of length 3, that keeps a graph from being bipartite.